# Using PETSc for a CFD problem where calculation of matrix elements is computationally expensive

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, computation, petsc

I am trying to use PETSc as a solver for a multiphase CFD code. The code is based on finite volume estimation. The calculation of matrix coefficients by themselves is time consuming, almost the same amount of time as solving the matrix. I have a highly optimized code to calculate the coefficients of linear system of equations. The code can be easily parallelized, as each matrix element is calculated independent of other elements. I was looking for similar PETSc example but all examples in PETSc tutorial are calculated with simple calculations. To further clarify, the main steps of the code are

1. Calculate the fluid properties for all grid blocks. The
   calculations for each grid is independent of other blocks.
2. Update the coefficients of linear system of equations.
3. Solve the matrix (using PETSc)

I am using object oriented C++.

Any resources or examples where calculation of matrix elements are computationally expensive?

Comment: Not sure what your "independent classes", so I'm not sure what the problem is. PETSc can construct the matrix in parallel, so if you can parallelize your coefficient construction you're done. You only say that you're doing CFD, but not what your numerical scheme is. If you're doing FEM, there is the potential problem that you want to parallelize the elements in your calculation, but PETSc has a variable-based partitioning scheme. This is no problem. Use `ADD_VALUES` to insert the element integrals into your matrix. If your problem lies elsewhere, explain.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, Thanks for your comment. This is a petroleum reservoir simulation model, similar to UTCOMP. Fluid properties are estimated with cubic EOS. The derivatives of fluid properties with pressure and composition are used to build the linear system of equations. The fluid property calculation (step 1) is implemented in a separate class, lets call it PPCK. PPCK is parallelized with MPI and doesn't interact with PETSc. After PPCK update fluid properties, a "Solver" object uses PETSC functions to construct the matrix and solve for pressures and fluxes.

Comment: Things like "petroleum" and "EOS" are irrelevant for computations. I asked if you were using FEM and you didn't answer that. But at least now I know that you seem to be constructing a matrix without using PETSc. That's the wrong design. You should immediately put everything in PETSc objects. Petsc is not a "solver" that you invoke at some point: it's a toolbox that you use throughout your code.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, sorry, I forgot to add that it is a finite volume code. I also updated the question.